# how to return an object from a key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return an object  based on a key, I managed to do that with the method below but still, I am wondering how to return the key and value `250: [176916, 176922, 176939],` instead of the value only `[176916, 176922, 176939]`

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
  325: [244050],
  400: [177100],
  500: [166743],
  700: [387789],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = [];
let notArrAcceptedValues = [];
const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
  acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues.push(...myObj[key])
    : notArrAcceptedValues.push(...myObj[key]);
});

console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });

//arrAcceptedValues result: [{250: [176916, 176922, 176939]}, {400: [177100]}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by whole object? You can do `arrAcceptedValues.push({...myObj})` if you want to push the complete `myObj`

Comment: i mean, return the key and value 250: [176916, 176922, 176939], instead of the value only [176916, 176922, 176939]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
  325: [244050],
  400: [177100],
  500: [166743],
  700: [387789],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = [];
let notArrAcceptedValues = [];
const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];
Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key,value]) =>{
    acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues.push({[key]: value})
    : notArrAcceptedValues.push({[key]: value});
});

console.log({arrAcceptedValues , notArrAcceptedValues })
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess you expect something like this:

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
  325: [244050],
  400: [177100],
  500: [166743],
  700: [387789],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = {};
let notArrAcceptedValues = {};
const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];

Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
  acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues[key] = [...myObj[key]]
    : notArrAcceptedValues[key] = [...myObj[key]];
});

console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });

//arrAcceptedValues result: [{250: [176916, 176922, 176939]}, {400: [177100]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
  acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues.push({ key: myObj[key]})
    : notArrAcceptedValues.push({ key: myObj[key]});
});
```

this will work for your case

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Object.keys, you could use Object.entries this is an easy way of getting the key & the value.

eg..

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
  325: [244050],
  400: [177100],
  500: [166743],
  700: [387789],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = {};
let notArrAcceptedValues = {};
const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];

Object.entries(myObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues[key] = value
    : notArrAcceptedValues[key] = value;
});

console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const myObj = {
      250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
      325: [244050],
      400: [177100],
      500: [166743],
      700: [387789],
    };
    
    let arrAcceptedValues = [];
    let notArrAcceptedValues = [];
    const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];
    
    Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
      acceptedValues.includes(key)
        ? arrAcceptedValues.push({ [key]: myObj[key]})
        : notArrAcceptedValues.push({ [key] : myObj[key]});
    });
    
    console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });
// {"arrAcceptedValues":[{"250":[176916,176922,176939]},{"400":[177100]}],"notArrAcceptedValues":[{"325":[244050]},{"500":[166743]},{"700":[387789]}]}
```

Comment: Will work for your case

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add details about why this should works ? Also it seems to be the exact same answer as the accepted one but not in snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
    const myObj = {
    250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
    325: [244050],
    400: [177100],
    500: [166743],
    700: [387789],
    };

    let arrAcceptedValues = {};
    let notArrAcceptedValues = {};
    const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];

    Object.keys(myObj).forEach((key) => {
    if (!(arrAcceptedValues[key] instanceof Array) && acceptedValues.includes(key)) {
      arrAcceptedValues[key] = [];
    }
    if (!(notArrAcceptedValues[key] instanceof Array) && !acceptedValues.includes(key)) {
      notArrAcceptedValues[key] = [];
    }
    acceptedValues.includes(key)
      ? arrAcceptedValues[key].push(...myObj[key])
      : notArrAcceptedValues[key].push(...myObj[key]);
    });

    console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

With for in loop

```js
const myObj = {
  250: [176916, 176922, 176939],
  325: [244050],
  400: [177100],
  500: [166743],
  700: [387789],
};

let arrAcceptedValues = {};
let notArrAcceptedValues = {};
const acceptedValues = ["250", "400"];

for(let key in myObj){
  acceptedValues.includes(key)
    ? arrAcceptedValues[key] = myObj[key]
    : notArrAcceptedValues[key] = myObj[key];
}

console.log({ arrAcceptedValues, notArrAcceptedValues });
```